# How to ask for a password after hibernate, but not after sleep in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I sleep the computer very often to increase battery life so it is unconfortable to type a password so often.

It would be nice to ask for a password after hibernate-restart-turn on the computer though.

Is it possible?

Comment: I need exactly this, but in windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible. Both Sleep and Hibernate imply you're away from your computer, so you're required to type your password if you're enabled the security feature.

On the other hand, you can choose to skip password prompt when the system is woken up from Sleep or Hibernate. Thus you'll be required to type your password only after restart or shutdown.

To change password options:

1. Click Battery icon on the Taskbar and then click **More Power options**.
2. Click **Change plan settings** link for a power plan.
3. Click **Change advanced power settings** link.
4. Click **Change settings that are currently unavailable** and confirm elevation.
5. The first item in the settings tree will be your power plan name, it has **Require a password on wakeup**.

   - Change **On battery** and **Plugged in** options to **Yes** or **No** depending on your needs.

Thus you may set to require password if computer is on battery and to skip it if it's plugged in.

Each power plan has distinct settings for requiring password after computer is woken up.